# Rails' script/server for a PHP project

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, webrick

Is there a simple HTTP server that can be run in the current PHP project path, like Rails' script/server (webrick)?

Comment: Why not install a LAMP/WAMP/MAMP? Getting an apache to work with PHP is 1000 times easier then getting it to work Ruby.,..

Comment: That may have been true a couple of years ago, but it is no longer the case, thanks to Phusion Passenger - http://www.modrails.com/

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is (much to my shock).  It's called [Nanoweb](http://nanoweb.si.kz/)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.phpontrax.com/

php on trax is basically Rails for PHP, im not sure if it features script/server. (cant read the site here as its filtered)